# Timed promise resolve returning immediately after having been resolved with time once before

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm struggling a bit on the wording here, but the gist is that I use a Promise.race that returns an object (As shown underneath). The majority of the time, at least a few of the promises will crash, but this is intentional. It just means a product was not found. To avoid the promise returning blank, I use a try catch block to start a new timed promise of 15 seconds. This prevents the promise from returning blank, letting the fastest function that finishes properly return their object to the Promise.race. This seemed to work just fine when testing in NodeJS 10 using Windows 10, but when I ported it to a Linux server running NodeJS 8 and Ubuntu 18.04, I got some odd behavior. The Promise.race works completely fine, until 15 seconds has passed since I first tested the function after booting up the NodeJS app. When those 15 seconds has passed, it will immediately return the timed promise when I try to race to normal promises.

I begin by racing these promises. (Not sure it matters, but this is called through an HTTP request)

```
let product = await Promise.race([
        get_info_meny_joker(bar_code, "meny.no"),
        get_info_meny_joker(bar_code, "joker.no"),
        get_info_openfoodfacts(bar_code)
    ])
```

One of them looks like this

```
async function get_info_meny_joker(bar_code, link) {

    try {
        let url = 'https://' + link + '/Sok/?query=' + bar_code

        let browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']})
        let page = await browser.newPage()

        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })

        let get_link = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.ws-product__title').getAttribute('href') )
        let product_name = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.ws-product__title').innerText )
let product_amount = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.ws-product__subtitle').innerText )
        let regex = "[0-9]+([gl]+|ml| [gl] | ml |kg| kg)"
        let match = product_amount.match(regex)
        match = match[0]
        /*let regex_index = new RegExp("[A-Za-z]")
        let index_match = regex_index.exec(match).index
        match = match.splice(index_match, 0, " ")*/
        product_amount = match

        await page.goto('https://' + link + '/' + get_link, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })

        const [first_product, second_product] = await page.$$('.ws-collapsable-block__heading');

        await page.screenshot({ path: "x.png" })

        second_product.click()

        await page.screenshot({ path: "y.png" })

        let img_url = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.lazyloaded').attributes[1].value)

        // Get a list of all the nutrients found on the page
        let nutrients_raw = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let nutrients_raw = document.querySelector('.ws-nutritional-content').children
            let nutrients = {}
            let i = 0
            for (let item of nutrients_raw) {
                nutrients[i + ""] = item.innerText
                i++
            }
            return nutrients
        });

        // Pretify the nutrients_raw to a nutrients object
        let nutrients = {}
        for (let i = 0; i < Object.size(nutrients_raw); i++) {
            let s = nutrients_raw[i]
            let type = s.slice(0, s.indexOf(':'))
            let amount = s.slice(s.indexOf(':') + 2, s.length)
            nutrients[type] = amount
        }

        return new Product(bar_code, product_name, product_amount, img_url, nutrients, link)

    } catch (err) {
        return await promise
    }

}
```

The timed promise looks like this

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let product = new Product()
    product.name = "Could not be located"
    setTimeout(() => resolve(product), 15000)
});
```

To repeat myself, I can Promise.race and it works completely fine, up till 15 seconds has passed since the first time I raced them.

(Not important to the question, but I understood the Promise.race function as completely deleting the losing promises from the stack. Odd that it remembers 15 seconds has passed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a fresh `promise` in this:

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let product = new Product()
    product.name = "Could not be located"
    setTimeout(() => resolve(product), 15000)
});
```

For each time you want to use it.  Otherwise, the timer has already been running for awhile when you start to use it and it will fire in far less than 15000ms because it's already been running for awhile.  In fact, if it's been longer than 15000ms since you created the promise, then it will already be resolved and when you use it in a `.race()`, the race will end immediately with this already-resolved promise.

> Not important to the question, but I understood the Promise.race function as completely deleting the losing promises from the stack. Odd that it remembers 15 seconds has passed.

That is not correct.  `Promise.race()` doesn't delete anything.  Any promises that lose the race keep going just fine.  It's just that the promise that `Promise.race()` returns will resolve as soon as the FIRST promise in the race finishes.  The others keep going just fine and will complete on their own schedule.

---

Probably what you want to do is to put this into a function and call that function, anytime you want a 15000ms promise:

```
function timeoutPromise(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let product = new Product();
        product.name = "Could not be located";
        setTimeout(() => resolve(product), t);
    });
}
```

Then, instead of the already saved `promise` variable you were using, you just call this function to get a new promise whenever you want to use a fresh  timeout promise.